# regex to check a number with format ab0ab0

Tags: regex, oracle

I'm trying to write a regular expression in oracle that match the following number format :
ab0ab0 where b can be strictly equal to a-1 or a+1

but I'm having difficulties with increasing or decreasing a digit value in regex.

I don't want to add all possible values in the regular expression with alternation.

what I'm done so far is : ^(\d)(\d)0\1\2(0)$
but it doesn't check if b=a-1 or a+1

Comment: Sorry, but alternations are the only regex way here as in Oracle, you cannot introduce any code inside the regex pattern (you could do that in Perl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from writing out all the options you could subtract one digit from the other:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( your_column, '^(\d)(\d)0\1\20$', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) )
       - TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( your_column, '^(\d)(\d)0\1\20$', 1, 1, NULL, 2 ) )
       IN ( -9, -1, 1, 9 )
```

*(`-9` and `9` will include the values `090090` and `900900` if you expect the subtraction/addition to wrap around - if you do not want these values then just use `-1` and `1`)*

or, check whether the 2-digit value is 1 or 10 modulo 11:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  MOD( TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( your_column, '^(\d\d)0\10$', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) ), 11 )
         IN ( 1, 10 )
OR     your_column IN ( '090090', '900900' )
```

Comment: can you please brief a little about first option? what is the \20 at the end of the regex ?

Comment: @user123 As per the regular expression in your question, `\2` is a back-reference to the contents of the 2nd capture group earlier in the regular expression and `0` is the character zero. So my regular expression is exactly the same as yours (except I left off the `$` - I'll edit that in) just with the `()` for the third capture group removed.

Comment: Thanks this is what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Just as Wiktor [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189946/regex-to-check-a-number-with-format-ab0ab0#comment85385069_49189946), you can't do it without alternations.

Went ahead and typed it out for you though.

```
^((01|12|23|34|45|56|67|78|89|90|09|98|87|76|65|54|43|32|21|10)0){2}$
```

Comment: Good answer. user123 will have to decide whether they want 90|09| in the string or not.

Comment: This doesn't check that ab = ab. It will match `120230`.

Comment: `^(01|12|23|34|45|56|67|78|89|90|09|98|87|76|65|54|43|32|21|10)0\10$` would fix that.